# DateTime.TryParseExact does not process long format strings

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have to try and parse out a date time from a string that is causing some trouble.

*Most* of the time the string will be as follows

```
'Sat Aug 10 08:01:37 2013'
        ^ note one space
```

My original date format for the `TryParseExact` was `'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy'`

However, on single digit days, what would normally be the digit in the ten's place is not deleted, but instead it is replaced by a space (see below)

```
'Wed Aug  7 08:01:37 2013'
        ^^ note the two spaces
```

My first idea was to simply remove all the spaces to achieve the format string:

```
'dddMMMdHH:mm:ssyyyy'
```

but my `DateTime.TryParseExact` fails and never accepts the newly formatted (spaceless) format string.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with `TryParseExact`, the spacing of the date is important.

It's a bit hacky, but if no better solution is presented, I would do a `TryParseExact` using `'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy'` and if that fails, another `TryParseExact` using `'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy'` (with the two spaces)

---

### **Edit**

I think I found a smarter way, pass `DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite` to the `TryParseExact` method.

According to the docs:

> Extra white-space characters in the middle of the string must be
>   ignored during parsing, except if they occur in the DateTimeFormatInfo
>   format patterns.

Not sure what it means by "except if they occur in the DateTimeFormatInfo format patterns." but it is worth a try.

Comment: I have not tried your edited solution, but you did answer the root of my question.

Comment: If you add extra spaces to the format string, e.g., "`MMM ___ dd`", then they will not be ignored, even with `DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite`.